My data isn't rendering on my page. The json seems to be pulling in correctly
I was practicing displaying data using handlebars and I am stuck. In my console I can see that it is pulling in the information from my api but my HTML within handlebars isn't rendering on the page. Can anybody tell me what is going on? This is my code it has all been built on a local server:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="meme-container">
        <!-- Create a container for the rendered memes -->
        <script id="meme-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

            {{#each memes}}
                <div class="memes">
                    <img src="{{url}}" alt="{{name}}">
                    <p>{{name}}</p>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
    </script>
    </div>
    <script>
        //script
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.get("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes", function (data) {
                const templateSource = $("#meme-template").html();
                const template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);
                const renderedHTML = template(data.data.memes); // Assuming the memes are in data.data.memes

                // Append the rendered HTML to a container on your webpage
                $("#meme-container").html(renderedHTML);
                // Handle the response data here
                console.log(data); // For testing purposes
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>

I have double checked that the names are what I thought, and nothing is misspelled.

Any console errors?

No there aren't

What is the output of console.log(data)?

All of the data from the api. This is a sample of it: {

In order for your template to iterate through the memes array, you will need it in the object you pass to your template function. Therefore, you should replace template(data.data.memes) with template(data.data).

I have moved the template out of the <div> and modified the code a little bit.
The name specified in {{#each memes}} should be a key in the object passed into the template(...) call.
const renderedHTML = template(data.data); // no need to pass since the template is going to look for key called memes in the passed object. 



$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes", function(data) {
    const templateSource = $("#meme-template").html();
    const template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);
    const renderedHTML = template(data.data); // no need to pass since the template is going to look for key called memes in the passed object. 

    // Append the rendered HTML to a container on your webpage
    $("#meme-container").html(renderedHTML);
    // Handle the response data here
    console.log(renderedHTML); // For testing purposes
  });
});
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="meme-container">
  </div>
  <!-- Create a container for the rendered memes -->
  <script id="meme-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    {{#each memes}}
    <div class="memes">
      <img src="{{url}}" alt="{{name}}">
      <p>{{name}}</p>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
  </script>
</body>

</html>



